# Default Text when choose Combo Box

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox

I have two combo boxes, ComboBox Country and ComboBox City. When I change value in ComboBox Country, ComboBox City will be filled with Cities from Country I choose in first combobox. Is it possible every time i change ComboBox Country value, the combobox City show "Please Choose City"?. Because in my current condition, ComboBox City will show the cities from country i choose (e.g London, Manchester). Here is my current code to fill ComboBox City

```
  dtTable = SQLqueryGetListCities
  ComboBoxCity.DataSource = dtTable
```

Comment: Add a default ListItem in the dropdown with value = "Please Choose City" and add `AppendDataBoundItems=true` so data is added *after* the default item.

Answer (score 0):

```
dtTable = SQLqueryGetListCities

DataRow dr = dtTable.NewRow();
dr["CityID"] = "0";
dr["CityName"] = "Select City";
dtTable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
dtTable.AcceptChanges();

ComboBoxCity.DataSource = dtTable
```

Comment: I added a just a simple row that will be part of data i.e. Select City and ID is 0 so it will be displayed first.
After adding row to datatable, i just assigned it as datasource